# How to restart "Into Darkness" in the Secret World?

Tags: the-secret-world

I started Into Darkness, but paused the mission halfway through to increase my skill lines before going back. Now I can't figure out how to restart the mission?

Since it was a mission started via a cell phone call, there isn't really a "go back to where you received the mission" option (that I'm aware of).

I tried going back to the New York park where you need to find the agent, but that didn't trigger it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to you Faction HQ to retrieve it. Where exactly depends of your Faction. According to [this forum thread](https://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?36855-How-do-I-regain-Into-The-Darkness-quest/page2):

- Dragon : On the pond outside the Dojun, next to the "Special Assignment" (Venetian Missile Crisis). (Confirmed by a friend)
- Templars : In Sonnac's room, on a desk behind him, next to the same mission. (Confirmed personally)
- Illuminati : In Kristen Geary's Room, on the desk, next to the same mission. (Not confirmed personally)

I have no proof, but it seems logical that the other faction missions (London Undergroud, To Catch A Thief, Rogue Agent) can be retrived at the same spot.